# Gulp доп. страницы

Tags: html, gulp, scss, index, page

Подскажите, как в dist добавить папку) pages?
Не понимаю, как доп. страницы генерировать в папке dist
[image]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Я так понял dist - это директория в которую файлы компилируются с папки src? Найдите фаил path.js в котором прописываются пути компилирования? Вам нужно создать в src создать папку pages и в ней создаёте pug файлы страниц, а в path.js нужно прописать пути - откуда компилировать и куда. У меня по крайней мере так работает